# Printing Unicodes in C++

Tags: c++, unicode-string

How to print Unicode in Loop in C++?
I Tried with this code.It does not work

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    wchar_t chr1=L'\u0985';
    while(chr1<=L'\u098C') 
    std::wcout<<(wchar_t)chr1++<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Define *"It does not work"* - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: and which platform is this? It's not easy to output Unicode on Windows cmd

Comment: My terminal is supporting unicodes I am able to print single character but not a range of Characters... When i Execute the above code it is showing all ?(question marks).I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Windows, try going onto command prompt, properties, font, and setting a font which include the Unicode characters you are trying to output.
If non-Windows, try setting a font similarly.

Comment: I am able to print single unicode but not a range of unicodes.When i execute the above code it shows all ?(question marks).I am using Ubuntu 16.04...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that your terminal (or font you set it to) does not support unicode, you should try using a different terminal, or setting your font to something that does support unicode

Comment: I am able to print single unicode but not a range of unicodes.When i execute the above code it shows all ?(question marks).I am using Ubuntu 16.04...